# Does updating a row with the same value actually update the row?

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-update, database-performance, postgresql-performance

I have a performance-related question. Let's say I have a user with the first name Michael. Take the following query:

```
UPDATE users
SET first_name = 'Michael'
WHERE users.id = 123
```

Will the query actually execute the update?  If so, how do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: technically, it'd have to do. there may be an `on update` trigger that would otherwise NOT get triggered if the db were to decide "hey, these values are the same, I'll just pretend I changed stuff".

Comment: Of course yes! If you don't want that, you must have a test before, and update if different.

Comment: x-posted to dba.SE: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/118178/3684

Answer (score 4):

Yes,  it is more efficient to do this

```
UPDATE users
SET first_name = 'Michael'
WHERE users.id = 123 
and (first_name <> 'Michael' or first_name is null)
```

It can make a lot of difference.
Not just the time for the update itself - it does not have to take am update lock.

Comment: Maybe you meant `AND first_name <> 'Michael'` ?

Comment: And it is not only about the locks. An update needs *three* disk- I/O s (per page). Avoiding idempotent updates avoids them. (on a page basis) On second thought: that could be *four* I/Os.

Comment: Generally this is the simplest answer and right to the point. I would say it's a rule of thumb with updates. But be aware of situation when you really want to `UPDATE` to happen (ex. you may have triggers `ON UPDATE` which you need to execute no matter if value really changed)

Comment: This can be a sneaky bug if `first_name` can be NULL. Consider my answer to the x-posted question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118214/3684

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Agree.  I just plain missed that.  Add or is null.

Answer (score 2):

The `UPDATE` in PostgreSQL doesn't check a difference between original and new value by default. You can skip useless updates with `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_trigger_skip()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  IF old IS NOT DISTINCT FROM new THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END;
$$;

-- run this trigger as first - start name with "_"
CREATE TRIGGER _omega_update_skip BEFORE UPDATE ON omega;
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_trigger_skip();
```

PostgreSQL execute triggers in order based on names of triggers. This solution is simple and generic, and **slow** (if you use massive updates - can be ok for few updated rows). There is a overhead of trigger execution. If you can, modify your queries, then do it - described by @Frisbee.